# How much computation can be performed in given time using given energy inside a ball of given volume?

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics

[Landauer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle) asserts that there are physical limits on computation given finite free energy (although there are ways around it).

$E=hc/\lambda$ provides a lower limit on the amount of energy for a particle in a ball of given volume.

Finally, I've heard through a grapevine of a recently computed limit on the amount of computation that can be performed in a given volume. However, I wasn't able to quickly find that paper  because the search for "computation" + physics terms leads to tons of papers on how to compute those physics terms rather their influence on computation.

Thus the question: could you either answer the title question or list a paper that does?

Thanks.

Comment: This paper may be of interest:
http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908043

Comment: Are you thinking of the Bekenstein Bound? Not very recent, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound

Comment: @JoelKlassen: thanks! It's exactly what I was looking for.